# Let $G=AB$ where $(|A|,|B|)=1$ and $V$ be an $\mathbb{F}[G]$ module.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Under these assumptions it is a well-known fact that if $V_A$ and $V_B$ are faithful ($V_A$ denotes $V$ as an $\mathbb{F}[A]$-module) then $V$ is also faithful.

Clearly if $V_A$ and $V_B$ is faithful then $C_G(V)=C_A(V)C_B(V)$ is trivially true ($C_G(V)$ denotes the kernel of the action of $G$ on $V$). What I wonder is whether the statement $C_G(V)=C_A(V)C_B(V)$ is true under the assumptions given in the heading.

($\mathbb{F}$ denotes an arbitrary field.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=C_G(V)$. As $N$ is normal in $G$, for a Hall $\pi$ subgroup $H$, $N\cap H$ is Hall-$\pi$ subgroup of $N$.

Then $N\cap A$ and $N\cap B$ are Hall $\pi \ and  \ \pi'$ subgroup of $N$.

Thus, it forces that  $N=(N\cap A)(N\cap B)$.

$N\cap A= C_A(V)$ and $N\cap B=C_B(V)$ completes the argument.